# Can we write a <block> in out layout file without any "type" parameter?

Tags: magento-1.8

Can we write a block tag in our layout without its type parameter, such as below

```
<block  name="formInput" template="Pfay/UserForm/FormInput.phtml" />
```

what is the other way to do this if i don't have any block associated to my template file ?

Comment: if you don't have any block type then you can write <block type="core/template" name="formInput" template="Pfay/UserForm/FormInput.phtml" />

Comment: This will also be helpful to get an understanding about the type parameter of blocks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633307/understanding-magento-block-and-block-type

Comment: @Sukeshini, thanks, the link was really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`type` attribute is mandatory. Or you can use `class` attribute instead of `type`, but both of same thing:

```
<block class="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
  ...
</block>
```

or

```
<block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
      ...
</block>
```

See this line (/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php):

```
protected function _generateBlock($node, $parent)
{
        if (!empty($node['class'])) {
            $className = (string)$node['class'];
        } else {
            $className = (string)$node['type'];
        }
        //....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

as you want to use a template, you have to use a type, which supports templates.
The most generic type you can use for this is `core/template`

As already said, you have to use a type, because there is no default type. On the other side there are a lot of blocks, which dont even support templates.